# Integration by Substitution, Converting dx to du

Tags: calculus, integration

Q: Using the substitution of $ u = \dfrac{e^{2x}}{5}$, write this integrand as a function of u: $$\int \frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt{25-e^{4x}}}dx$$

I'm stuck at substituting u into the denominator. The best I can get is:
$$\int \frac{5u}{\sqrt{25-{ \frac {5}{2} (\frac{2}{5}e^{4x}})}}du$$

I've tried making it $$\int \frac{5u}{\sqrt{25-{ \frac {5}{2} (\frac{2}{5}e^{2x}})^2}}du$$ but i guess it's wrong too as the items in the bracket will also be squared which is wrong.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: $e^{4x}=(e^{2x})^{2}=25u^{2}$. Also $dx=\frac 5 {2u} du$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!!!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why are you answering in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $5u=e^{2x}$ then $5du=2e^{2x}dx$ or $\dfrac52du=e^{2x}dx$ so
$$\int \frac{e^{2x}dx}{\sqrt{25-e^{4x}}} = \int \dfrac{\dfrac52du}{\sqrt{25-25u^2}}=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

Comment: I was just about to write something like this, but then I got a visitor in my office. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $e^{2x}=5\sin\theta$.

Comment: Even though that might be a good substitution to do, it does not answer the question asked, as far as I can see.

Comment: @mickep The question was “Can anyone help me with this?” Giving *hints* to practice problems from homeworks etc. is standard practice here. Keep challenging yourself, make the above substitution, and see where it takes you....